# Can the zero of $f(x)=\arccos(x)+(C (1 - x^2) - x) \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ be calculated explicitly, or is it transcendental?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have the equation
$$f(x) = \arccos(x) + (C(1 - x^2) - x)\sqrt{1 - x^2}$$ where the parameter $C$ is a real number. When $-\frac{2}{3} ≤ C$, the function has one real zero at $x = 1$. When $C$ drops below $-\frac{2}{3}$, a second zero appears, starting at $x = 1$ and decreasing towards $x = -1$ as $C$ tends towards $-∞$.

**I want to find the exact position of that second zero in terms of $C$, if possible.**

I've tried rearranging it to isolate $x$, but I can't seem to get it entirely outside of any trig functions. Using numerical calculations to plot the $x$-value against $C$ shows a curve that looks very close to the shape of $\frac{4}{π} \arctan\left(C + \frac{2}{3}\right) + 1$, just with some $C$-dependent horizontal scaling that I haven't been able to pin down yet, which makes me hopeful that a closed-form solution exists.

**Does such a solution exist? Or is it transcendental due to the presence of $x$ inside the $\arccos$ function?**

Comment: Wolfram alpha does not find closed form even for fixed values, so I'm not so confident that it exists

Comment: It is trancsendental because of addition algebraic and inverse trigonometric functions

Comment: One can write $x$ in terms of inverse functions, because one can express $C$ from $f(x)=0$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha Plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=parametric+plot+%28-csc%28a%29%5E2+%28-cos%28a%29%2Ba+csc%28a%29%29%2C+cos%28a%29%29+from+a%3D0.01*pi+to+a%3D0.99*pi)

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\pi+i\ln(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)+(C(1-x^2)-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$, $x\to -\frac{1}{2}i\frac{-1+t^2}{t}$: $C-2ti+3Ct^2+8i\ln(t)t^3+4\pi t^3+3Ct^4+2it^5+Ct^6=0$

Comment: with $x=\cos(t)$, you would calculate $2t-\sin(2t)+2c\sin^3(t)=0$ which looks like a [Kepler equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation), but is more complicated. Maybe techniques used to solve it can be used to solve this question’s equation.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a number can be represented explicitly (means [in closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)) or not has nothing to do with whether it is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) or not. Numbers that are not transcendental are [algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number). There are algebraic numbers that cannot be represented explicitly (means usually [representable in radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_in_radicals)), and there are transcendental numbers that can be represented explicitly, e.g. $e$ and $\pi$.

My answer concerns solutions in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

$$\arccos(x)+(C(1-x^2)-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\pi+i\ln(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)+(C(1-x^2)-x)\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$$

We see, because your equation can be rearranged to  a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials and without univariate factor, we don't know how we can solve the equation by rearranging for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation. But in some cases, we can try to guess solutions (1 is a solution of your equation).

for real $x$:

$x\to -\frac{\frac{1}{2}i(-1+t^2)}{t}$:
$$\frac{1}{8}Ct^6+\frac{1}{4}it^5+\frac{3}{8}Ct^4+it^3\ln(t)+\frac{1}{2}\pi t^3+\frac{3}{8}Ct^2-\frac{1}{4}it+\frac{1}{8}C=0$$
$t\to e^u$:
$$\frac{1}{8}C(e^u)^6+\frac{1}{4}i(e^u)^5+\frac{3}{8}C(e^u)^4+iu(e^u)^3+\frac{1}{2}\pi(e^u)^3+\frac{3}{8}C(e^u)^2-\frac{1}{4}ie^u+\frac{1}{8}C=0$$

It seems these equations cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W, Generalized Lambert W (see [Mező]) or Hyper Lambert W (see [Galidakis]).